# custom visual studio 2013 theme

Tags: visual-studio-2013, themes, settings

I installed Visual Studio 2013, set it to dark theme, and imported settings for son of obsidian style.
And now it looks like this:

[image: my visual studio]

What I am trying to achieve is to get rid of the annoying white bar, which has been dark before the son of obsidian settings was imported.

Do you know where in the setting can I set the color of this bar?

Comment: Off topic but how did you make your VS editor dark theme? Is a  setting to get the theme switched? Thanks!

Comment: @KalaJ by default Visual studio 2012 comes with Light or Dark (and latest versions have Blue) Its one of the first settings. Tools / Options / Environment / General / Visual experience / Color theme. There is also an official add-on that expands the number themes.
The vast majority of text editor themes (as opposed to the whole IDE skin) come from importing .vssettings file with Tools / Import and Export Settings Wizard.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `TextEditor - Indicator Margin BackGround` The default color in VS2012 is `FF333333` if you look in the Son of Obsidian Settings you will find that it is set to:

```
<Item Name="Indicator Margin" Foreground="0x02000000" Background="0x00F0F0F0" BoldFont="No"/>
```

Which is a  gray with its alpha channel set to 0, you could try editing the Settings file and importing it again, or you could just go to `Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Colors`. Keep the Show settings on the Text Editor selected and go to `Indicator Margin` in the Display Items(*fourth item down on my system*).

[image]

You can then click the Custom button for the Item Background which will bring up a Color Selection Dialog and you should make it look like this, to put it back to the original settings.

[image]

Comment: and do you have any idea how to make methods of classes have different color than the class instance ? For example : Console.WriteLine() -> Console : color1 , Method WritLine : color 2 ... thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JohnSmith Not without playing with the various Display Items. Looking at your example it looks like C++ and there are a whole bunch of options there.

Comment: @JohnSmith if you go to http://studiostyl.es/schemes/create and hover over the items you want to change it will give you the name if it is changable, which you can then use in Visual Studio Fonts and Colors Editor to change.

Comment: Both are marked as identifiers :/ but in visual studio 2010 it is possible, maybe in vs 2013 it is not ..

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using the [VS2013 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe)?

Comment: Question was clearly for VS2013 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe

Comment: That's wonderful that they came out with a 2013 version now, I'll update my edit to reflect this, however if you check the release date it was released 16 days after I posted this.